# Installing clang on debian 11

Tags: clang, apt, apt-get

I am on `Debian version: 11.6` and trying to install the `clang` package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install clan
```

However I am getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang
```

I have tried with specific versions: `-6` or `-7`.
I have ran the following commands as advised in multiple posts:

- `sudo apt-get clean`: does not change anything
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`: run successfully but still same error
- `sudo apt-get update`: getting some weird error:

```
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease [17.9 kB]
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease                                                    
Hit:4 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease                                                       
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
Hit:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                      
Hit:5 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:8 https://packages.stripe.dev/stripe-cli-debian-local stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Not sure what the issue with mysql or how to solve it nor whether this is really what is preventing me from installing clang?